# Issue with dictation and UITextfield

Tags: uitextfield, tvos, apple-tv, dictation, siri-remote

On tvOS 9.2, I have an issue when setting the `UITextField` keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

It seems when you start dictation, no input is added. Is this a bug? Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Are you sure that the country/region which is selected in Settings supports dictation?

Comment: actually I found out that dictation is disable for UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad